# How to add a list item to an existing list using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to add a list item to the current list items using javascript but the code is only adding the text and not replicating what the other list items look like. How can I add the list item exactly the same way the other items look?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <title>Practice Manipulating the DOM</title>
 </head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1></h1>
    <p class="desc"></p>
    <ul>
      <li><input> Play music</li>
      <li><input> Swim</li>
      <li><input> Bike ride</li>
      <li><input> Code</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="extra">
      <p>This is extra content you need to delete.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
// 5: Create a new list item and add it to the <ul>
let ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
let li = document.createElement('li')
ul.appendChild(li).innerText ='Programmer';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
let li = document.createElement('li')
ul.appendChild(li).innerHTML ='<li><input>Programmer</li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like so

```js
let ul = document.querySelector('ul');
let li = document.createElement('li')
let input = document.createElement('input')
li.append(input);
li.append(' Programmer');
ul.append(li);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1></h1>
  <p class="desc"></p>
  <ul>
    <li><input> Play music</li>
    <li><input> Swim</li>
    <li><input> Bike ride</li>
    <li><input> Code</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="extra">
    <p>This is extra content you need to delete.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is add the inner text before appending the `<li>` element. So you can get that text to live within the `<li>` tags. Like so:

```js
let ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
let li = document.createElement('li');
li.innerText = 'Programmer';
ul.appendChild(li);
```

This way the `<li>` gets your text as you might have expected it to. Which results in the following HMTL:

```html
<ul>
    <li>Programmer</li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively you could give the `<li>` an innerHtml with a `<p>` so it's not empty text inside the list item. Makes for better markup practices because it's easier to manage, read, and style text that's within appropriate tags. See below example for innerHTML:

```js
let ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
let li = document.createElement('li');
li.innerHTML = '<p>Programmer</p>';
ul.appendChild(li);
```

to get a result like below:

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>Programmer</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Finally bringing it all together, you'll see below using the innerHTML approach, but you can swap out with the innerText if that's preferred:

```js
let ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
let li = document.createElement('li');
li.innerHTML = '<p>Programmer</p>';
ul.appendChild(li);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <title>Practice Manipulating the DOM</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1></h1>
    <p class="desc"></p>
    <ul>
      <li><input> Play music</li>
      <li><input> Swim</li>
      <li><input> Bike ride</li>
      <li><input> Code</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="extra">
      <p>This is extra content you need to delete.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the input element

```
let ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
let li = document.createElement('li')
li.innerHTML = " <input> Programmer";
ul.appendChild(li);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a list item in an easy way, you could use jQuery,

```
$('ul').append("<li>What you want in your list item</li>");
```

Another way to do it in Vanilla JS is,

```
document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML = "<li><input> Play music</li>
                                          <li><input> Swim</li>
                                          <li><input> Bike ride</li>
                                          <li><input> Code</li>
                                          <li>What you want in your list item</li>";
```

Comment: if you are using multiline, then tild is better than quotes